# C++ - Making an event loop

Tags: c++, events, event-loop

Does anyone know how to make an event loop in c++ without a library? It doesn't have to be cross-platform, I'm on a Mac. Basically, I want the program to run and do nothing until the user presses the up arrow key, then the program will output "You pressed up" or something. All i can think of is having an infinite `while` or `for` loop and get input with `cin`, but I don't think `cin` can detect arrow keys and I believe it pauses the program until it reaches a '\n';

I would want it to look like this:

```
void RUN()
{
   while(true)
   {
      // poll events and do something if needed
   }
}

int main()
{
   RUN();
}
```

I'm kinda sure it's possible without threads, and I've heard that this can be accomplished with `fd_set` or something, but I'm not sure how.

Any help would be really appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The program *has* to run in the background when there aren't any events. For example, Microsoft Word doesn't stop until the user presses a button, it keeps running. I want something like that, but command-line not GUI.

Comment: You're going to have to use a library if you want to detect keyboard input such as an up arrow key.

Comment: Well libraries just use system code right? I just want to know that system code.

Comment: If you want to do this while completely avoiding 'libraries' (which I take it includes system libraries) you're looking at writing a very large amount of very low level code. You'd probably have to start with some assembly to do system calls, and then build routines to use those system calls and then build on top of that to interface with device drivers, etc. You might want to think about just using the libraries your platform provides for this.

Comment: Okay, maybe system libraries (I dont want to learn assembly right now, maybe later), but nothing else

Comment: I am pretty sure Microsoft Word behaves, in this regard, like any reasonable program does, and spends 99% of its time just sitting there, doing nothing. I.e., it essentially “stops”. Don't do busy polling. Tell the operating system you're waiting for something to happen. `cin.get()` does that, if you're just waiting for a single key press. To get more low-level, you could check the `select` function, too. Then again, I'd only go there when I've tried simple things like `cin.get()` and they couldn't do what I needed.

Comment: why don't you take a look at epoll() function. libev is based on it. epoll() is part for standard unix based OS distribution. Also look at setjmp function. I wrote a code that uses setjmp and signals sometime back to restart my code on CTRL+C. But to read keystrokes (without getch()) and their value you will have to know a profound understanding of code.

Comment: @rcplusplus - When a program executed by a shell, running in a terminal, is put into the background it is **disconnected** from the keyboard. What is it you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking keyboard input, and not looking for a Mac look and feel, what you want is the UNIX way of doing it.  And that is,

1) set the terminal in either raw or cbrk mode (I forget which).
2) now use read() to read single characters at a time.
3) temporarily echo the character read (as an int) so you can find what the up arrow key gives you.

As for the more general event loop question, where the only input device is the keyboard, you sit in a loop, and whenever a key is typed (in raw mode?) you call a routine with the value of the key typed.  If you had more input devices, you would need multiple threads each could listen to a different device, putting what they find on a queues (with appropriate locking).  The main loop would then check the queue and call a routine appropriately everytime something appears in it.

Comment: but would `read()` cause the program to stop until input is entered?

Comment: read() normally blocks (meaning yes).  And if the only thing you're doing is waiting for input that is the right thing.  Otherwise, you can use select() to determine whether read would have any input before doing the read(), if you want to do other things inbetween times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ncurses](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/ncurses.3x.html) and enable [cbreak](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/curs_inopts.3x.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/curs_inopts) to get the raw input stream.

Answer (score -1):

I've used a while loop with signal handlers.  Like this incomplete snippet.

```
void getSomething()
{
  std::cout << "Enter new step size: "; std::cout.flush();
  std::cin >> globalVariable;
  std::getchar();  // consume enter key.
}

void printCommands()
{
  std::cout << "1: do something\n"
        << "q: quit\n"
    << "h: help\n"
    << std::endl;
}

void getCommand()
{
  // Output prompt 
  std::cout << "Enter command ('h' for help): "; std::cout.flush();

  // Set terminal to raw mode 
  int ret = system("stty raw"); 

  // Wait for single character 
  char input = std::getchar(); 

  // Reset terminal to normal "cooked" mode 
  ret = system("stty cooked"); 

  std::cout << std::endl;

  if (input == 'h') printCommands();
  else if (input == '1') getSomething();
  else if (input == 'q') {
    g_next = true;
    g_quit = true;
  } 
}

void 
signalHandler(int signo)
{
  if (signo == SIGINT) {
    g_next = true;
  } else if (signo == SIGQUIT) {
    getCommand();
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
  signal(SIGUSR1, signalHandler);
  signal(SIGQUIT, signalHandler);

  do {
    // Stuff
  } while (!g_quit);

  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: wouldn't `getchar()` pause the program? And are `g_quit` and `g_next` user defined?

Comment: Hmm, yes, it does pause, and also doesn't just detect the keystrokes as they're typed, but requires you to ctrl-c to get the prompt. g_quit and g_next are user defined globals, but they could be anything you want.

Answer (score -1):

The question has been updated to say "The program has to run in the background ... but command-line not GUI."

All traditional; *NIX shells that can put a program into the background also disconnect the program's standard input from the terminal, so AFAIK, this has become impossible.

---

This does not need to be Mac specific. The Mac supports  *NIX mechanisms for reading characters from a keyboard.

AFAICT all the program is doing is waiting for a character, so it might as well block.

Normally the terminal device, tty  (teletype!), is interpreting characters typed on the keyboard before your program can read them from standard input. Specifically the tty device normally buffers an entire line of text, and intercepts the rubout character (and a few others like CTRL+w) to edit the line of text. This pre-processing of characters is called a 'line discipline'

You need to set the tty device driver to stop doing that! Then you can get all of the characters the user types.

You change the device using ioctl or termios on the file descriptor.

Search for e.g. "ioctl tty line discipline raw" to understand the details, and find program examples.

You can set the terminal to 'raw' using the command line program `stty`. 
Please read the stty man page because setting it back can be slightly tricky (NB: if you make a mistake it is often easier to kill the terminal, than try to fix it, because there is not echoing of anything you type)

It is possible that the up-arrow is not a single char, so it will require some byte-at-a-time decoding to avoid blocking at the wrong point in the input stream, i.e. if some input sequences are one character, and others two, or three characters, the decoding needs to happen at each byte to decide if there is a pending byte, or one too many read's might get  issued, which would cause the program to block.